Having difficulties hiding a picklist value with a Custom permission and a Validation rule
I need to be able to hide one picklist value from a field on a Custom object from a set of users. I've created a Custom permission (View All Statuses), and a Permission set to assign to users who should be able to view all values, but the validation rule does not seem to be working.
Here's the syntax that I have, and there isn't an error there:
AND(
    NOT($Permission.View_All_Statuses ),
    ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Deactivated")
)

However, a user that does not have that permission assigned - still sees the value.

The validation rules are designed to prevent a user from saving a record with certain values, rather than hiding those values from the picklist itself.
To hide a picklist value from a set of users, you would typically need to use record types and page layouts. Record types allow you to define different sets of picklist values for different users, and page layouts can be used to control which fields and picklist values are visible or editable by certain profiles or permission sets.
